# Firebase data takes a couple of seconds before showing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase and javascript to write/read and store data. The problem is when the page is loading, all firebase related content takes a couple of seconds to show. So if a user is visiting his/her profile, their name, for instance, takes time to show and until it has loaded it is blank.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You forgot to share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Add your data in cache. Fetching data form firebase is asynchronous.

Comment: @GabrielDiez how can I do that? I for instance have this code on a page: `document.querySelector('.showNameOnCard').innerHTML = name.toUpperCase();` and the name is gotten here: `return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        const name = snapshot.val().name;`

Comment: You can use http://hoangnd.me/blog/cache-your-data-with-javascript-using-cachejs For caching data you fetched previously. Share the code in your main post please otherwise we can't help you